# Deeplink opened from Facebook App goes to PlayStore

Tags: android, facebook, branch.io

The deeplinking works fine from WhatsApp, Slack and even Facebook Messenger but doesn't work from the Facebook App itself.

In the branch.io Link Settings I did enable:

- ✓ Always try to open app
- ✓ Enable App Links + SHA256 Cert Fingerprints
- Changed to custom Link Domain: sharing.kptncook.com
- successfully authenticated the "Facebook Install Ads"

Facebook developer settings:

- Packagename, class name and hashes are correct(Facebook login also works fine)
- ✓ SSO is activated
- ✓ Deep-Link is activated

Android App Versions:

- Facebook Messenger: 126.0.0.9.84
- Facebook: 133.0.0.19.83

Example link: sharing.kptncook.com/pIbQ/FKktug85TE

Activity part of Manifest:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="kptncook" android:host="open" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="sharing.kptncook.com" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="sharing.kptncook.com" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="io.branch.referral.InstallListener" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Branch branch = Branch.getInstance();

    branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener(){
        @Override
        public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
        }
    }, this.getIntent().getData(), this);
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    this.setIntent(intent);
}

}
```

Additional info: In the emulator some links won't open and some does. If I send a link that doesn't work from the emulator to a real device it works on the real device.

What am I doing wrong?

Update:
New shared links work now on the Real device in both Facebook Messenger and Main App. But if I open the exact same link in the messenger on an emulator it redirects to "r31v.test-app.link..." and doesn't show anything except a toast "Can't load page". It's so frustrating. Any ideas how to debug it?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your own questions by removing information and replacing it with "solved". Feel free to close your own questions if they are transient or irreproducible, and/or upvote and accept answers that helped you solve it. If no answer truly covers the fix, feel free to answer your own question!

Comment: @KubaOber You might haven't seen it but I tagged Alex Bauers answer as solved before you wrote that comment. And why did I remove the last part? I thought it leads to confusion because the emulator isn't representative for branch io testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here:

Facebook deep linking is one of the hardest things to debug — [they intentionally don't want users to leave their app](https://blog.branch.io/deep-linking-from-facebook-in-2017/), wherever possible.

A few notes for debugging:

1. The domain `r31v.test-app.link` is your original link domain. You customized this to `sharing.kptncook.com`, but there are times when Branch needs to use both to handle certain edge cases. You need to add the following lines to your Manifest:

   `<data android:scheme="https" android:host="r31v.test-app.link" />
   <data android:scheme="https" android:host="r31v-alternate.test-app.link" />`
2. Other than the above, your in-app configuration implementation looks fine.
3. It's possible something is funky with your Dashboard configuration. Branch has separate [Test and Live environments](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/integration-testing/guide/ios/), and you're currently using the Test one. It's important to make sure you haven't split your implementation between values from both sides.
4. Deep linking behavior frequently doesn't work correctly in the emulators. It's *always* best to test with real devices, because results from emulators are usually not reliable.
5. Facebook sometimes caches the App Links tags, which means you may get unpredictable results when opening a URL that has *just* been shared, or when re-sharing a URL that has been posted before with different data.

Feel free to reach out to our [Integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) any time with questions!

Comment: Thank you so much :) 1. is fixed / 3. seems to be correct / 4. explains a lot. But I still have problems. It works perfectly fine on my Samsung S7 but if I install the exact same app on a different device (Huwei) and click the same link I get redirected to the PlayStore. From both the Facebook App and the Slack App. Any quick ideas? I will probably write the team later

Comment: Happy to help! Any time.